# Having issue with animating Qt Widget with QTimer(exit with code 255)?

Tags: qt, animation, qtimer

I want to animate Qt Widget with QTimer (Without Animation System) and painting,so i put a timer and starting point in enterEvent and in timercall slot i make border bigger and so on...
but It just doesn't run and say application exit with code 255:

.h

```
#include <QtWidgets>
class QWidget;
class QPainter;
class QTimer;

class Sample : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Sample(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Sample();
private:
    QTimer *timer;
    int weight=1, step=1;
protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    virtual void enterEvent(QEvent *);
public slots:
    void timercall();
};
```

.cpp

```
Sample::Sample(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
   connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(timercall()));
}

Sample::~Sample() {}

void Sample::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * ) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black,weight));
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    QRect Rectangle=QRect (10,10,width()-20,height()-20);
    painter.drawRect(Rectangle);
}

void Sample::enterEvent(QEvent *) {
    timer->start(100);
}

void Sample::timercall() {
    weight+=1;
    if (step > 10) {
        timer->stop();
    }
    step++;
    repaint();
}
```

And then when i remove this line from my code:

```
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(timercall()));
```

in enterEvent the application crash happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private:
    QTimer *timer;
```

You never create the object referenced by your `timer` pointer.

Declare `QTimer timer` instead, as it's an internal object there's no need to use a pointer.